# Stanford CoreNLP: Can I retrieve parent Annotation (i.e., document) from a contained CoreMap (i.e. sentence)?

Tags: stanford-nlp

I'm just getting started with CoreNLP. From all the code samples I've seen (particularly the one on CoreNLP's main website: http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp.shtml#Usage), I've gathered that Annotation objects hold the annotated document, and CoreMap objects hold the sentences (if "ssplit" annotation is enabled).

To keep my code lightweight, I'm only passing CoreMap to one of my functions. However, in one instance I need to retrieve the parent Annotation document object. Is there any backpointer using the CoreMap object, or will I have to pass in the Annotation object to my function as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The overall document is an Annotation.  The Annotation contains a List which contains the sentences.  Each sentence is a CoreMap.  I don't know of any way to get the parent Annotation from a CoreMap, so I would just pass the Annotation object to your function.

Comment: Thank you! Many parse trees have a parent pointer, so figured there might be something similar. I might as well just pass the whole object.